# unable to read csv file from synapse spark scala notebook

Tags: azure-synapse

I am try to read csv file from synapse notebook but it's giving an error path does not exist. I have read many documents, saying have configure something on blob storage or in synapse workspace to read the azure blob storage.

please help here. i am trying read csv file from blob storage not data lake gen2.

Comment: The best thing to do is to try and find the file in the Data > Linked hub in Azure Synapse Studio.  Then right-click it and select one of the options, eg load to dataframe or SELECT TOP 100.  This will create a script for you with the right path and if that does not work then your issue is most likely permissions.  Ensure you have the Storage Blob Data Contributor on the storage account.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am try to read csv file into dataframe and I am getting an error path doesn't exist but I am giving direct path on wasbs still same error is it also same permission issue

Answer (score 0):

> If you are receiving the path doesn't exists, please do check if the path exists on the storage account.

OR

> You can try the below method to read csv file from Synapse Spark Python Notebook.

[image]